# Keras scale Image Data to value between -1 and 1 with ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I' m using Keras to train a ConvNet. This Net needs Data values between -1 and 1. However my image-values are between 0 and 255. How can I do this with ImageDataGenerator?
I' m already rescaling the values to a range between 0 and 1 with the following code:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
```

P.S. I know how it is done mathematically ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with the arguments in ImageDataGenerator https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

The following arguments might solve this problem for you:

- featurewise_center: Boolean. Set input mean to 0 over the dataset, feature-wise.
- samplewise_center: Boolean. Set each sample mean to 0.
- featurewise_std_normalization: Boolean. Divide inputs by std of the dataset, feature-wise.
- samplewise_std_normalization: Boolean. Divide each input by its std.